# Failing to send Wake-On-LAN UDP packet with netcat

Tags: network, bash, mojave, wake-on-lan

I'm trying send a WOL packet from a bash script under Mojave, much like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588036/9370650, without any third-party utilities, such as the nifty https://github.com/jpoliv/wakeonlan.

I don't, however, seem to be able to successfully broadcast anything at all to 255.255.255.255 on port 9 using netcat.

If I listen to UDP port 9 like this:

`$ nc -uv -l 9 -w0`

netcat then reports the WOL packet when I run the perl-based `wakeonlan` script I mentioned above.

But, if I try to do my own UDP broadcast to 255.255.255.255:9, like this:

`$ echo "hello" | nc -vu 255.255.255.255 9`

it isn't seen by my listening instance of netcat.

For the record, the output from my attempt to broadcast looks like this:

```
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif (null)
    src 192.168.1.7 port 51674
    dst 255.255.255.255 port 9
    rank info not available
```

I'm not a networking expert, so I'm likely misunderstanding something here.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've *likely* answered my own question:

The BSD version of `netcat` included with macOS lacks the `-b` (broadcast) flag.

And even though `255.255.255.255` is a special global address for broadcasting to the entire subnet, simply sending to it apparently isn't enough to imply/accomplish a broadcast without that missing `-b` flag.

So, my impression is that the macOS version of `netcat` simply won't do what I'm trying to do.

If I were to install an alternate `netcat` implementation using homebrew or some other source, it might accomplish it--but at that point, I'd rather just depend on having `wakeonlan` installed.

I'll leave this answer here, but unaccepted, hoping that someone with more low-level networking know-how provides a better answer at some point.

*Edit:* Also, if one were going to install other software due to `netcat` limitations, it looks like `socat` *(described as "netcat on steroids")* would likely be something to seriously consider, instead of just an alternate version of `netcat`.